# Limit the number of items that can be entered in a SharePoint 2013 List using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to make a web page for event registration. I have a page connected to the list on SharePoint and I want to make a condition with JS limiting the number to 50 people.

I've tried this solution but it doesn't work:
[How to Limit the number of items that can be entered in a SharePoint List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796007/how-to-limit-the-number-of-items-that-can-be-entered-in-a-sharepoint-list)

Answer (score 0):

I think js solution is not the best way.The js solution will only be triggered under certain circumstances.
I would recommend you create a event receiver(Item Adding,Item Updating) to limit the number if the list.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdding(properties);
            if (properties.List.ItemCount >= 50)
            {
                properties.Cancel = true;
                properties.ErrorMessage = "Contain too much item";
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
            }                                
        }
```

[How to: Create an event receiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-an-event-receiver?view=vs-2019)

Comment: i will try that

Answer (score 0):

Use OnPreRender functio. You will have to read the whole list and then not display the Form but a message.

But you can do without CSR and make SharePoint do half the work for you.

A quick and easy ductape patch from the olden days is to hide the NewForm contents.

On the NewForm.aspx page add a ListView WebPart, make it list all your items
change the WebPart Layouts Properties Zone-Index to 1 to make it display below the NewForm
Add another WebPart, use a Content Editor WebPart with the contents:

```
<script>
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function () {//execute after pageload
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-itmhover');//all displayed listitems
        if (items.length > 10) {//maximum number of items
            var form = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-formtable')[0];//new form
            while (form.tagName !== 'DIV') {//go up to the enclosing DIV
                form = form.parentNode;
            }
            form.innerHTML = '<h1>Numbers of records has exceeded the permitted limit: ' + items.length + '</h1>';
        } else {//optional: hide the View with all the items
            var itemlist = items[0];//first item
            while (itemlist.tagName !== 'DIV') {//go up to enclosing DIV
                itemlist = itemlist.parentNode;
            }
            itemlist.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Tip: place the javascript in a separate file and link the Content Editor Web Part to it.. makes it easier to edit... you still have to include the < script> tag!!

[image]

Another alternative is:
[Limit only one entry per day per user in sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list/156829#156829)